# Is this HQL/SQL query possible? Java, Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have multiple Entities mapped to my MySQL database and I can map those entities into relevant objects using Spring's CrudRepository. The three entities are: Snapshot, Market, and Contract

Each Snapshot contains a unique id, a timestamp, and a List of Market objects

Each Market contains a unique primary key id, a nonUniquemarketId, name, url, ...., and List of Contract objects.

Each Contract contains fields regarding pricing information.

The nonUniqueMarketId is an id given by the API I am getting data from. It only occurs once in each Snapshot's List of Market objects

I am wondering if it is possible to get the List of Contracts from a specific Market in List of Markets from a specific Snapshot. That is, if I have a Snapshot's timestamp and a nonUniqueMarketId, is it possible to write a query that looks at all the Snapshots in the DB, gets the one with the given timestamp, then looks at that Snapshot's List of Markets and either gets that Market whose nonUniqueMarketId is given or the List of Contracts field in it?

More generally, I know what Snapshot I want and what Market I want, is it possible to get that specific Market given those two parameters?

Snapshot.java

```
package com.axlor.predictionassistantanalyzer.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Snapshot{

    @Id
    private Integer hashId;

    @JsonProperty("markets")
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) //ALL, not persist
    private List<Market> markets;

    private long timestamp;

    public Snapshot(List<Market> markets, long timestamp, Integer hashId) {
        this.markets = markets;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.hashId = hashId;
    }

    public Snapshot() {
    }

    public void setMarkets(List<Market> markets){
        this.markets = markets;
    }

    public List<Market> getMarkets(){
        return markets;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Integer getHashId() {
        return hashId;
    }

    public void setHashId(Integer hashId) {
        this.hashId = hashId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Snapshot{" +
                "hashId=" + hashId +
                ", markets=" + markets +
                ", timestamp=" + timestamp +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Market.java

```
package com.axlor.predictionassistantanalyzer.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Market {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer marketUniqueID;

    @JsonProperty("timeStamp")
    private String timeStamp;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("image")
    private String image;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("shortName")
    private String shortName;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) //ALL, not persist
    @JsonProperty("contracts")
    private List<Contract> contracts;

    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;

    public Market(String timeStamp, String image, String name, int id, String shortName, List<Contract> contracts, String url, String status) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.contracts = contracts;
        this.url = url;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Market() {
    }

    public Integer getMarketUniqueID() {
        return marketUniqueID;
    }

    public void setMarketUniqueID(Integer marketUniqueID) {
        this.marketUniqueID = marketUniqueID;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }

    public List<Contract> getContracts() {
        return contracts;
    }

    public void setContracts(List<Contract> contracts) {
        this.contracts = contracts;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n\nMarket{" +
                "marketUniqueID='" + marketUniqueID + '\'' +
                ", timeStamp='" + timeStamp + '\'' +
                ", image='" + image + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", shortName='" + shortName + '\'' +
                ", contracts=" + contracts +
                ", url='" + url + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                "\n}";
    }
}
```

Contract.java

```
package com.axlor.predictionassistantanalyzer.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class Contract {

    /*
Why do we need contractUniqueID?:
    See explanation in Market.java
    Basically, the JsonProperty 'id' field cannot be used as a primary key in the database. We need to create one, so we generate it here.
 */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer contractUniqueID;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("image")
    private String image;

    @JsonProperty("lastClosePrice")
    private double lastClosePrice;

    @JsonProperty("bestBuyNoCost")
    private double bestBuyNoCost;

    @JsonProperty("bestSellNoCost")
    private double bestSellNoCost;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("displayOrder")
    private int displayOrder; //not sure what this even is supposed to do lol

    @JsonProperty("dateEnd")
    private String dateEnd;

    @JsonProperty("bestSellYesCost")
    private double bestSellYesCost;

    @JsonProperty("bestBuyYesCost")
    private double bestBuyYesCost;

    @JsonProperty("lastTradePrice")
    private double lastTradePrice;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("shortName")
    private String shortName;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;

    public Contract(String image, double lastClosePrice, double bestBuyNoCost, double bestSellNoCost, int displayOrder, String dateEnd, double bestSellYesCost, double bestBuyYesCost, double lastTradePrice, String name, int id, String shortName, String status) {
        this.image = image;
        this.lastClosePrice = lastClosePrice;
        this.bestBuyNoCost = bestBuyNoCost;
        this.bestSellNoCost = bestSellNoCost;
        this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
        this.dateEnd = dateEnd;
        this.bestSellYesCost = bestSellYesCost;
        this.bestBuyYesCost = bestBuyYesCost;
        this.lastTradePrice = lastTradePrice;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Contract() {
    }

    public Integer getContractUniqueID() {
        return contractUniqueID;
    }

    public void setContractUniqueID(Integer contractUniqueID) {
        this.contractUniqueID = contractUniqueID;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public double getLastClosePrice() {
        return lastClosePrice;
    }

    public void setLastClosePrice(double lastClosePrice) {
        this.lastClosePrice = lastClosePrice;
    }

    public double getBestBuyNoCost() {
        return bestBuyNoCost;
    }

    public void setBestBuyNoCost(double bestBuyNoCost) {
        this.bestBuyNoCost = bestBuyNoCost;
    }

    public double getBestSellNoCost() {
        return bestSellNoCost;
    }

    public void setBestSellNoCost(double bestSellNoCost) {
        this.bestSellNoCost = bestSellNoCost;
    }

    public int getDisplayOrder() {
        return displayOrder;
    }

    public void setDisplayOrder(int displayOrder) {
        this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
    }

    public String getDateEnd() {
        return dateEnd;
    }

    public void setDateEnd(String dateEnd) {
        this.dateEnd = dateEnd;
    }

    public double getBestSellYesCost() {
        return bestSellYesCost;
    }

    public void setBestSellYesCost(double bestSellYesCost) {
        this.bestSellYesCost = bestSellYesCost;
    }

    public double getBestBuyYesCost() {
        return bestBuyYesCost;
    }

    public void setBestBuyYesCost(double bestBuyYesCost) {
        this.bestBuyYesCost = bestBuyYesCost;
    }

    public double getLastTradePrice() {
        return lastTradePrice;
    }

    public void setLastTradePrice(double lastTradePrice) {
        this.lastTradePrice = lastTradePrice;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contract{" +
                "contractUniqueID='" + contractUniqueID + '\'' +
                ", image='" + image + '\'' +
                ", lastClosePrice=" + lastClosePrice +
                ", bestBuyNoCost=" + bestBuyNoCost +
                ", bestSellNoCost=" + bestSellNoCost +
                ", displayOrder=" + displayOrder +
                ", dateEnd='" + dateEnd + '\'' +
                ", bestSellYesCost=" + bestSellYesCost +
                ", bestBuyYesCost=" + bestBuyYesCost +
                ", lastTradePrice=" + lastTradePrice +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", shortName='" + shortName + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to query/get market/markets based on snapshot.timestamp and market.nonuniquemarketid ?

Comment: yes, if that is possible.

Comment: I don't see any relationship between Snapshot -> Market -> Contract. I mean no Snapshot in Market and no Market in Contract. Why?

Comment: The schema contains a collection of Snapshots basically. Each Snapshot contains a list of Markets. Each Market contains a list of Contracts. If I have snapshot.timestamp and market.nonuniquemarketid, can I get a Market from that? A Contract does not know what Market it belongs to. A Market does not know what Snapshot it belongs to, so I don't know if this is possible. I don't know SQL or ORM super well yet.

Comment: if u said all entities mapped to database then there's should be a relationship key between them. Seen in your Entities there should be Snapshot object in Market and Market object in Contract. So then you can create HQL/SQL for what you want.